# Check solr/home property and the logs . ClassCastException: class org.apache.lucene.analysis.icu.ICUFoldingFilterFactory

Tags: java, solr, tomcat6

once I start Eclipse telling him where solr is via

```
`-Dsolr.home=D:\devel\apps\solr-4.3.1_master\ec2`
```

starts solr but appears the following exception .

```
2014-11-04 16:50:50,711 INFO [main] CoreContainer - New CoreContainer 1552134420
2014-11-04 16:50:50,713 INFO [main] CoreContainer - Loading CoreContainer using Solr     
Home: 'D:\devel\apps\solr-4.3.1\ec2\'
2014-11-04 16:50:50,714 INFO [main] SolrResourceLoader - new SolrResourceLoader for  
directory: 'D:\devel\apps\solr-4.3.1\ec2\'
2014-11-04 16:50:50,716 INFO [main] SolrResourceLoader - Adding
'file:/D:/devel/apps/solr-4.3.1/ec2/lib/alista-solr-plugin-1.4.0_RC1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar' t
o classloader
2014-11-04 16:50:50,717 INFO [main] SolrResourceLoader - Adding    
'file:/D:/devel/apps/solr-4.3.1/ec2/lib/est-solr-lib-2.6.8.jar' to classloader
2014-11-04 16:50:50,718 INFO [main] SolrResourceLoader - Adding    
'file:/D:/devel/apps/solr-4.3.1/ec2/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.33-bin.jar' to classl
oader
2014-11-04 16:50:50,901 ERROR [main] SolrDispatchFilter - Could not start Solr. Check   
solr/home property and the logs
2014-11-04 16:50:50,929 ERROR [main] SolrException -    
null:java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError at 
org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.reloadLuceneSPI(SolrResourceLoader.java:205)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.<init>(SolrResourceLoader.java:115)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.<init>(SolrResourceLoader.java:250)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.load(CoreContainer.java:380)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.load(CoreContainer.java:358)
    at  org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$Initializer.initialize(CoreContainer.java:326)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.init(SolrDispatchFilter.java:124)
    at   

  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:298)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4076)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4730)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:583)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:675)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:601)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1317)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1065)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:822)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.apache.lucene.analysis.icu.ICUFoldingFilterFactory
    at java.lang.Class.asSubclass(Class.java:3126)
    at org.apache.lucene.util.SPIClassIterator.next(SPIClassIterator.java:137)
    at org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.AnalysisSPILoader.reload(AnalysisSPILoader.java:79)
    at org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.AnalysisSPILoader.<init>(AnalysisSPILoader.java:60)
    at org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.AnalysisSPILoader.<init>(AnalysisSPILoader.java:49)
    at org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.TokenFilterFactory.<clinit>(TokenFilterFactory.java:31)
    ... 33 more

2014-11-04 16:50:50,931 INFO [main] SolrDispatchFilter - SolrDispatchFilter.init() done
Nov 04, 2014 4:50:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory docs
```

I'm newbie in solr and I'm a bit lost regarding to this topic . Does anyone looks anything that might help me to solve the issue .

Thanks in advance

Comment: Still having the same problem . Seems has no solution .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok . I have found the problem . The thing is that I copied 'lucene-analyzers-icu-4.3.1.jar' and 'lucene-analyzers-smartcn-4.3.1.jar' in **solr/lib** folder, and in **Apache Tomcat/lib** folder, so them crash . I deleted the ones that were in tomcat .